How do I make my discord bot recognise bad words even if they have spaces or non-letter characters in between?
This is my code for my discord bot. I wanted to make the bot also to delete messages that contain bad words that have characters (. , * / _ - and space character) in between each letter of the words.
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from replit import db

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.messages = True

automod = False
intents.messages = True

db = {}
def update_encouragements(encouraging_message):
    if "encouragements" in db.keys():
        encouragements = db["encouragements"]
        encouragements.append(encouraging_message)
        db["encouragements"] = encouragements
    else:
        db["encouragements"] = [encouraging_message]

def delete_encouragment(index):
    encouragements = db["encouragements"]
    if len(encouragements) > index:
        del encouragements[index]
    db["encouragements"] = encouragements

with open("bad_wrods.txt", "r") as t:
    bad_words = t.read().splitlines()

def get_user_mention(mention):
    if mention.startswith('<@') and mention.endswith('>'):
        return client.get_user(mention[2:-1])

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands(message)
    global automod
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.author.bot:
        return
    if automod:
        if any(word in message.content.lower() for word in bad_words):
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send(
                f"Nuh uh, {message.author.mention} Please do not use bad words."
            )

    if message.content.startswith("$automod-toggle") and message.author.id in [
            822685628201697311, 998625868643565640
    ]:
        if automod:
            automod = False
        else:
            automod = True
        await message.channel.send(
            f"Automod is now {'enabled' if automod else 'disabled'}")
        
        else:

Is there anything that I can do to improve it?
I made a file that contains all the bad words. I tried to make copies of the words and put in the same file but I added space between the letters. It didn't work and also not effective because there's more than just the space character.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem

So, to be clear: you want every letter in a bad word to be separated by the given charaters? "bad_word" or "ba-d_wo rd" would be ok then, right? Aside from botting it, regular expressions could be a way to solve it, by identifying possible bad words.

Ah! This is fun puzzle, so there are many ways to achieve this, you can look into more complex ones later if you wanted to, for now let me give you an simple one that will just remove non alphabetic characters from a string/message.
Here is the basic code:
clear_word = ''.join(char for char in unclear_word if char.isalpha())

You can use this however you like, it would be better to create a seperate function to achieve this, for example (this is not the most optimized way to do this but will give you an idea):
def is_a_bad_word(unclear_word, badwords):
    clear_word = ''.join(char for char in unclear_word if char.isalpha())
    for bword in badwords:
        if clear_word.lower() == bword.lower():
            return True
    return False
    


Yes this is a simple start point for a bot filter. Bot filters always works by adding new ways on top. I can already see how to implement like generally used characters instead of letters like "3" as "e"
